# Visual Studio - New Filter instead of New Folder when using Create Project From Existing Source Wizard

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I used the Create Project From Existing Code Wizard for Visual Studio 2008, but apparently projects created this way do not allow you to create virtual solution folders, and instead only allow you to create actual system folders. I would like to have the standard project setup of Header Files, Resource Files, and Sources Files, but I seem to be unable to create the virtual files required. Is there any way to change the project so that it allows virtual folders to be created?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

At least for a C++ project created this way (not sure about other languages), the "Show All Files" button/option in the Solution Explorer is enabled which gives the behavior you're seeing.

Disable that option by clicking the icon and you'll get the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: This sounds like what I want, and it is a C++ project, but I don't see anything resembling a "Show All Files" button/option at all.

Comment: At the top of the Solution Explorer pane I get 2, 3 or 4 icons depending on whether the current selection is the solution, a project or something inside a project.

If I have a project or something inside a project selected, the first icon/button is for 'Properties' and the second is for "Show All Files".

Comment: Quite helpful. Thanks