# Filters in a VS2010 project lost after a restart

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I had organized my files (.cpp and .h) in a VS2010 C++ project into separate filters. After a sudden restart the folders are gone but the files are still there . Is there any way for me to recover those folders or do i have to reorganize again ?

Update:
It seems that when i right click on the project I do not get the add new filter option instead i get add new folder option. How do i add new filters to this project now

Comment: interesting. so they were logical folders possibly. maybe you can instead organize this on disk and include existing folders

Comment: To prevent similar losses in the future consider using an Git integration plugin and setup a local git repository (VS 2013 integrates Git by default but you need plugins for earlier versions). As an unrelated aside; this helped me stop commenting out a bunch of code (instead just commit and then delete it) and makes adding experimental features very easy with branches.

Comment: This post [helped][1]

The show all files button was enabled

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815993/visual-studio-new-filter-instead-of-new-folder-when-using-create-project-from

Comment: NOTE COMMENT ABOVE:  Check that the "Show ALL Files" icon is NOT clicked on!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prefer physical file-system directories instead of logical filters, you can click on the "Show All Files" button atop the Solution Explorer panel and create the directories from within Visual Studio.

[image: Show All Files]

This method doesn't require a .vcxproj.filters file and gives you the option to keep your file structure sane (i.e. not having an enormous amount of files in a single directory).

Answer (score 2):

In VS2010, they aren't folders, they're *filters*.  They are logical groupings that are managed in your .vcxproj.filters file, which is XML-based (make a new C++ project and take a look at the file in a simple text editor, if you're curious).  Most likely, that file got corrupted or wasn't saved properly when you had the sudden restart, and you'll have to reorganize them again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently with a C++ project in VS2019, where the project filters had disappeared. The root cause was that the `.vcxproj.filters` XML file had become corrupted somehow and a `</ClCompile>` closing tag was left out. The IDE does not display any obvious error for it and simply flattens the filters.

With hindsight, time could be saved by checking the `.vcxproj.filters` XML file in another app, e.g. XML Notepad to validate the XML document for any structural or encoding issues.

https://microsoft.github.io/XmlNotepad/